# Can I input a List of strings to a function that takes a string as input (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming I have a function:

```
def prinLetter(letterInput):
    print("Letter " + letterInput)
```

and I have a list of letters:

```
list1 = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Is there any possibility in python to write something similar to

```
printLetter(list1)
```

instead of having to write the following?

```
for i in list1:
    printLetter(i)
```

I am basically trying looking for a 'cleaner' method in one line

Thank you! :)

Comment: That loop looks perfectly fine. Why don't you like it?

Comment: Are you looking to call the function for each individual letter in the list, or just once for the entire list? If it's the former, then your loop works just fine.

Comment: No. You obviously can't pass a list to that function, because it has no idea what to do with that list. And the loop solves your problem elegantly in a single additional line. You won't find anything "cleaner" than that. That's exactly what loops are for, after all.

Comment: one-liners can't solve everything. When functions have a side-effect, you can't (or shouldn't) use them.

Comment: If you _really_ want a one-liner, here you go: `list(map(printLetter, list1))`. This will create a potentially huge list of `None`s, though.

Comment: @ForceBru and that's discouraged, because it's relying on map/listcomps to perform side-effect only tasks, where loops are all right.

Comment: one liner: `for i in list1: printLetter(i)`

Comment: All you can do to make it better is `for i in list1:printLetter(i)`, which is nothing different, but hey, one line -_-.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @StefanPochmann Im from an R background and learning Python, in R you could have for example used printLetter(LETTERS) and it would have worked. Was wondering if there is something similar in Python :)